# SQL request: Join the same table

Tags: sql, join

Suppose I have this table `"tab"`:

```
-------------------
id | value | name |
-------------------
1  | 12    | 'to' |
-------------------
2  | 13    | 'to' |
-------------------
3  | 14    | 'gh' |
-------------------
```

I want to get the lines that have the same names but diffrent values. In this case, it would be the first and second line.
I did this request:

```
select *
from tab t1
join tab t2 
on t1.ID = t2.ID 
where t1.VALUE != t2.VALUE
and t1.NAME = t2.NAME
```

But it's taking way too long to give me the results.
So I was wondering if there was another quicker solution?

Thanks!

Comment: Does it even work? `on t1.ID = t2._ID `

Comment: I'd do `where t1.VALUE < t2.VALUE`, do avoid repeated values (switched order).

Comment: Do you have indexes on the table?

Comment: how it will be 1st and 2nd line if have same value but different name?

Comment: You said in the question `lines that have the same values but diffrent names` but your query and other description says opposite, did you mean `same name but different values`?

Comment: @juergen d: no indexes

Comment: @jarlh: still takes a lot of time...

Comment: @dardy: Then add indexes! They make the table selects soooo much faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this solution if you don't need join

```
SELECT *
FROM tab t1
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 'x'
               FROM tab t2
               WHERE t2.id <> t1.id
               AND t2.name = t1.name
               AND t2.value <> t1.value
              )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select t1.* from your_table as t1 inner join
(
select name from your_table
group by name
having count(distinct value)>1
) as t2 on t1.name=t2.name
```